# Get input field contents and append to HTML <div> element

Tags: jquery, input, append

I'm trying to get the contents of an input field and add them to my HTML document.

Here's what I have, but it's not working, yet:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>To Do</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>To Do</h2>
            <form name="checkListForm">
                <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
            </form>
            <div id="button">Add!</div>
            <br/>
            <div class="list"></div>
        </body>
    </html>

            $(document).ready(function(){
        var input = $("input[name=checkListItem]");
        $("button").click(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){   

var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    });
            $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
        });
    });
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Change `toAdd` to `$(input).val()`

Comment: You really messed up the code with your edit @user3472810

Comment: Ugh. No. I just realized I left something out in my original post. It wasn't working, anyway, though. Sorry! jQuery beginner! Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you have a few mistakes:

1) `$("button")` should be `$("#button")`

2) `$("input[name=checkListItem]")` should be `$("input[name='checkListItem']")`

3) put `var input = $("input[name='checkListItem']").val();` inside  **click** event

and do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function(){

       var input = $("input[name='checkListItem']").val(); 
       // .val() will give textbox value

       $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + input + '</div>');
     });
```

});

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/u5H2x/1/)

or more simply:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#button").click(function(){

    $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + $("input[name='checkListItem']").val()+ '</div>');

   });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now! I kept messing it up by adding/changing things to try to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @user3472810 just understand it and then use it you will get it how it is done

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var input = $("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + input + '</div>');
    });
});
```

button is a div, not a html element, so add #

Comment: in your code `input` is already a jQuery object, no need to wrap it again in `$()` to get the value